# using delimiters to separate multiple parts

Tags: php

I have this data i would like to extract year built:2012,location:Prestigious business,cleaning:Daily office cleaning services in PHP;

```
a:8:{s:10:"Year Built";s:4:"2012";s:8:"Location";s:28:"Prestigious business address";s:8:"Cleaning";s:30:"Daily Office Cleaning Services";s:11:"Maintenance";s:29:"Common Area Maintenance (CAM)";s:9:"Utilities";s:49:"Air conditioning, electricity and water utilities";s:9:"Furniture";s:17:"Already Installed";s:6:"Access";s:27:"24/7 365 Access To Building";s:10:"Lobby Area";s:21:"Friendly Receptionist";}
```

I have this so far i have been able to extract all but for `s:4:` and `a:8:{s:10:`

Comment: Could you please add your current code to the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, it's serialized.  Just `unserialize()` and access the array:

```
$result = unserialize($data);
echo $result['Year Built'];  // 2012
```

Doing a `print_r($result);` yields:

```
(
    [Year Built] => 2012
    [Location] => Prestigious business address
    [Cleaning] => Daily Office Cleaning Services
    [Maintenance] => Common Area Maintenance (CAM)
    [Utilities] => Air conditioning, electricity and water utilities
    [Furniture] => Already Installed
    [Access] => 24/7 365 Access To Building
    [Lobby Area] => Friendly Receptionist
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `serialize` Just use `unserialize`, you will got the array.

```
$arr = unserialize("");
print_r($arr );

echo $arr['Year Built']; //2012
echo $arr['Location']; //Prestigious business address
```

Now you can access this array, you will get the values:

```
Array
(
    [Year Built] => 2012
    [Location] => Prestigious business address
    [Cleaning] => Daily Office Cleaning Services
    [Maintenance] => Common Area Maintenance (CAM)
    [Utilities] => Air conditioning, electricity and water utilities
    [Furniture] => Already Installed
    [Access] => 24/7 365 Access To Building
    [Lobby Area] => Friendly Receptionist
)
```